# Volume potential for Laplace equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $L^p$ source term

Tags: reference-request, laplacian, potential-theory, fundamental-solution

It is known that the solution of

$$-\Delta u = f \quad \text{in } \mathbb{R}^3$$

can be represented through the volume potential

$$ Vf(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} E(x-y)f(y) \, dy, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^3, $$

where $E(x-y)$ denotes the fundamental solution in dimension three, provided $f$ has some regularity. Whether we talk about classical or weak solutions, it is usually assumed that $f$ has compact support in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I was wondering: are there similar results available in the case $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^3)$ with a suitable decay behaviour at infinity ? For instance, if

$$ f(y) = O(|y|^{-3}) \quad \text{as } |x|\to \infty,$$

then $f(y)E(x-y)$ seems to decay well enough to ensure convergence of the integral. Nevertheless I could only find results that require $f$ to be compactly supported and that's also what the classical proofs exploit.

Comment: See [Folland's PDE text](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equ/p2XcDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover) (page 76, theorem 2.21) for a statement of the theorem for $f\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ if $n\geq 3$. He leaves the generalization to $f\in L^p$ as an exercise (see exercise 4 in the same section).